# How to use a display nsstring content in uiwebview?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsstring

I have an nsstring which basically contains Html and JavaScript code in the string. How can I use the string so that I can display that content in the uiwebview. Actually I'm planning to display google charts.

**Note**: I don't want to use a separate html file. I want to use nsstring because I get the some values from objective c code and then I'm planning to display on the uiwebview. I appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `NSString` is indeed an HTML string you should be able to load it into a `UIWebView` like so:

```
// Create and add a webview
UIWebView * myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:myWebView];

// Load the webview with HTML
NSString * myHTMLString = @"<HTML><BODY>Some HTML Code</BODY></HTML>";
[myWebView loadHTMLString:myHTMLString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I used just nsstring. It is just a string which has html and JavaScript code in it. Like this: nsstring *code=@"html code";

Comment: @user4150758 I added an `NSString` to my answer. Does that help clarify it?

Comment: Worked flawlessly :). Thank you. I tried it before the way you said but it didn't worked at that time. Anyways I got to know that I am thinking the right way and appreciate your help.